# Pass object into ng-model in selectbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an selectbox that is filled with data from my backend. The data that comes from my backend Is an array with objects:

```
 [Object { superkund_id="4", nod_id="12068", namn="Växjö Fagrabäck"}, Object { superkund_id="5", nod_id="9548", namn="Halmstad Bågen / Pilen"}]
```

I use ng-options to make the options In the select:

```
<td><select class="form-control input-sm2" ng-model="selectedSupercustomer" ng-options="item.superkund_id as item.namn for item in superkundOptions" ng-change="onChangeSuperCustomer(selectedSupercustomer)" ><option value=''>Select</option></select></td>
```

As you can see, I capture the the selected option with onChangeSuperCustomer:

```
 $scope.onChangeSuperCustomer = function(selectedSupercustomer) {
           //console.log(selectedSupercustomer); 
        }
```

The thing I want Is to pass the whole object that belongs to the selected option, so I can access all the properties that belongs to It. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Just to be clear, you are trying to access `superkundOptions` inside of `onChangeSuperCustomer` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your ng-options to bind the entire object `item`, instead of just `superkund_id`:

```
<td><select class="form-control input-sm2" ng-model="selectedSupercustomer" ng-options="item as item.namn for item in superkundOptions" ng-change="onChangeSuperCustomer(selectedSupercustomer)" ><option value=''>Select</option></select></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply by passing 'item' in 'onChangeSuperCustomer' method

```
<select class="form-control input-sm2" ng-model="selectedSupercustomer" ng-options="item.superkund_id as item.namn for item in superkundOptions"
     ng-change="onChangeSuperCustomer(item)" >
 <option value=''>Select</option>
</select>
```